# Odd coding style of IF block in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Where I work, I see lot's of the following type of code written in PL/SQL,

```
IF a>b THEN
  NULL;
ELSE
  c:=a*b;
END IF;
```

I find this odd because a C equivalent would look like this,

```
if (a>b)
{

}
else
{
  c=a*b;
}
```

And the above type of code has been frowned upon as bad style in a C forum that I know when posted by newbies.
As PL/SQL doesn't allow empty blocks and always require a NULL statement, does this type of coding style bring any advantages w.r.t readability or is it just a matter of preference?. FWIW, the guy who coded PL/SQL with the above style certainly seems to be a seasoned coder.
Is there any advantage compared to the following?

```
IF a<=b THEN
  c:=a*b;
END IF;
```

Comment: There is no functional difference therefore it's pure preference.

Comment: There might have been something else in the THEN clause that got deleted. This is an easy way to delete it.   Not what I'd do but it works.

Comment: @BrianRoach: There is a functional difference when `a` or `b` is `null`. See Maep's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that `a <= b` will *not* be true if any part is null. That's why these two statements are different.

In the first case, `c = a*b` will run if `a` is null. In the second case, it won't. Unless you know for certain that `a` and `b` are not null, the equivalent statement would instead be:

```
IF a<=b or (a is null) or (b is null) THEN
  c:=a*b;
END IF;
```

Comment: This may be the precise semantics; if so, it violates the principle of least surprise pretty greatly.  Both the designer of PLSQL and any coder that really intends this ought to shot.   Any newbie (or old fogey like me) that doesn't know this will modify this code incorrectly, raising maintenance costs.

Comment: How does this violate the principle of least surprise? It's pretty explicit in the cases it's testing for.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we do not like to have the empty blocks, so we always code ours like your bottom example, without the `ELSE IF`.  I think it's largely a matter of preference though, but I would rather reverse the `IF` statement as you did at the end to avoid the empty block; I find the code easier to read.